# File upload not posting data to iframe

Tags: php, forms, iframe, file-upload

I have a simple file upload form which posts to an iframe and the i retrieve the value from the iframe and redirect to another page.

The problem is the form isnt posting to the iframe (i dont think) so none of the php is being executed and null is being return to the javascript.

HTML Code

```
<form id="upload" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="index.php" target="upload_target">
   <input name="folder" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $folder ?>"  />
   <input name="filename" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $filename ?>"  />
   <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" size="5120" id="uploaded_file" accept="image/jpeg"  />
    <input id="sent" name="sent" type="submit"  value="Upload" />
</form>
<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:10px; height:10px; display:none"></iframe>
```

Javascript to get the value from iframe

```
$('form#upload').submit(function(){  

    $('#upload_wrapper').hide();
    $('#loading').show();

    // get the uploaded file name from the iframe
    $('#upload_target').unbind().load( function()
    {                               
      var img = $('#upload_target').contents().find('#filename').html();
      alert(img); //returning null
      $('#loading').hide();

     });
});
```

And the PHP at the top of the page to upload the file

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$targetFolder = $_POST['folder'] . "/";
$filename2 = $_POST['filename'];

if (!is_dir($targetFolder)) 
{
    mkdir($targetFolder, 0777);
}

    $tempFile = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];

    $uploadfile = $targetFolder. basename($filename2 .".jpg");
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$uploadfile);
    $fileName = $uploadfile;

    echo "<div id='filename'>$fileName</div>";

}
```

This code has been working before so im unsure at why it has stopped now please help.

Comment: the iframe content is on same domain of your web page?